# CRUD easyadmin ManyToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, orm, easyadmin, vichuploaderbundle

I currently trying to make a small application with 2 entities

1 entitie "Voiture" and one entitie "Media"

1 voiture can get several Medias.

I succesfully set up the eadyadmin package, I can add / edit / delete voiture entity with success.
But when I try to add images with my car (create / update) i got an error :

```
INSERT INTO medias (image_name, image_size, updated_at, voiture_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["spain-flag-icon-32-603796786ea83340987603.png", 1289, "2021-02-25 12:22:16", null]
```

I added the associationField tag, but without any luck
I think i miss somethign somewhere, but a little bit "lost".
I put the entity and crudcontroller here :
https://gist.github.com/julienanquetil/4cee2a0f0780b43d897f6269a830db46

if someone can help me to find what I made wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't set `$voiture` value, you can do this in a setter or adder method:

```
public function setImages($images): void
{
   foreach ($images as $image) {
      $image->setVoiture($this);
   }

   $this->images = $images;
}
```